# Has anybody fully implemented an XText editor in an IViewPart

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

Basically I need to implement a full XText editor in an `IViewPart`. I have most of it working based on the [XText Forms Integration](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/xtext-forms-integration/) project. Unfortunately, this is *not* a full implementation on an XText editor, and I wondered if anybody are aware of better starting points.. or even complete implementations :-)

Comment: What parts are missing to make the Xtext Froms Integration a full implementation?

Comment: @Sebastian (I'm on vacation right now, but of the top of my head..) Line numbers, integration with CMS

Comment: Any news on that front? Is there a full implementation available somewhere? Thanks

Comment: I have added some of the missing parts to my implementation. Though, my guess is that with Xtext 2, I probably have the re-implement a larger part of the code again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible since 2.2 (see [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/775682/#msg_775682)).
This code worked for me:

```
IEditedResourceProvider resourceProvider = new IEditedResourceProvider() {

        @Override
        public XtextResource createResource() {
            try {
                MyDslQueryStandaloneSetup.doSetup();
                ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
                Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("somefile.MyDsl"));

                return (XtextResource) resource;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    MyDslActivator activator = MyDslActivator.getInstance();
    Injector injector = activator
            .getInjector(MyDslActivator.QUERYNAME);
    EmbeddedEditorFactory factory = injector.getInstance(EmbeddedEditorFactory.class);
    handle = factory.newEditor(resourceProvider).withParent(
            parent);

    // keep the partialEditor as instance var to read / write the edited text
    partialEditor = handle.createPartialEditor(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I just find this project: [http://xrepl.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20141218121811/http://xrepl.org/)

They create a custom console command, so I think is a step closer to what we need... :)