# How to edit an attribute using Xtext?

Tags: xtext, emf

I want to use Xtext's editor to edit a String attribute of an EObject instead of editing a text file. How can I achieve this? I found [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/171206/) but it only mentions the workaround of creating a temp file. There must be a more elegant solution. I thought of creating a custom `EditorInput` but I'm not sure where to start. Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [2.2](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/releasenotes/2.2.0/new_and_noteworthy.php#Xtext), the supported solution is using [`IEditedResourceProvider`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.3/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/embedded/IEditedResourceProvider.html) with an [`EmbeddedEditorFactory`](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.3/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/embedded/EmbeddedEditorFactory.html) (since editing an attribute belongs to an embedded editor anyway). Sample code in Xtend (the attribute is updated whenever the editor changes):

```
val injector = MyDslActivator.instance.getInjector(MyDslActivator.COM_EXAMPLE_MY_DSL)
val resourceSet = injector.getInstance(IResourceSetProvider).get(null)
val fileExtension = injector.getInstance(Key.get(String, Names.named(Constants.FILE_EXTENSIONS)))
val resourceProvider = [|
    resourceSet.createResource(createURI('''temp.«fileExtension»''')) as XtextResource
]
injector.getInstance(EmbeddedEditorFactory).newEditor(resourceProvider).withParent(parent) => [
    createPartialEditor("", editedAttribute ?: "", "", false)
    document.addModelListener[_ | editedAttribute = document.get]
]
```

Based on: [EditTemplateDialog source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.xtext.ui.codetemplates/ui/2.4.2/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/codetemplates/ui/preferences/EditTemplateDialog.java#EditTemplateDialog), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817384/90874), [Eclipse Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/440717/987818/#msg_987818).